# How to change the numbering system of figures in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, captions, counters

This is probabily a very simple issue but I only have used templates of LaTeX so far and I am not used to the coding itself.
I have a template that uses the numbering of figures as for example Figure `III.C` or Figure `IV.A`. I want to change the numbering of figures for it to be simply numbers, (i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`... etc) no matter the section I am in currently. Thank you in advance.

My packages are the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load the borderline-obsolete `times` font package. Instead, load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will make these changes in my later posts here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you remove -- or, at least, comment out -- the instruction

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

that's currently in your document's preamble.

Given your write-up, it looks like you also have an instruction lying around somewhere that instructs LaTeX to use alphabetical labels ("A", "B", etc) instead of Arabic numerals ("1", "2", etc) to number `figure` environments. If this impression is correct, you should either remove this instruction or insert the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I appreciate it!